# Distribuir Crystal Report

Tags: c#, relatório, crystal-reports

Tenho uma aplicação rodando em C# windows Form, e **preciso instalar o Crysal Report na maquina do cliente**. teno esse **msi CRforVS_13_0_5**, mas quando ele é execultado na maquina cliente, e diz que só pode ser instalado junto com o Visual Estúdio.
**Em Outras palavras preciso saber se alguém já passou por isso e como resolver?

Existe algum outro instalado no Crysal Report que possa ser instalado junto com a aplicação?**
*Por Favor ajude-me.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: instala o odbc de 32 e 64bits. depois configura a conexao. executar...odbc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passei pelo mesmo problema...

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Os executáveis que estão descrito como **MSI** são os que você deve instalar na máquina do cliente!

Comment: Vou tentar instalar aqui

Comment: Caso não consiga, por favor me avise o problema.

Comment: O Run time foi blz, mas agora está dando um msg de erro dizendo. Falha ao abrir a conexão. Presumo que seja a conexão ODOBC, do crystal. Estou usando a versão 13 do crystal, baixe e instalei a versão 13.  http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_13.zip

Comment: Não entendi. A falha acontece em que situação?

Comment: Quando clico no botão para gerar o relatório. Ele aparece uma msg dizendo que conexão falhou, mas não é conexão com o BD, em relação o sistema, é somente com o relatório

Comment: vou editar a pergunta e deixa a msg de erro

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Nesse caso será necessário abrir uma nova pergunta detalhando como está seu Report, como ele está recebendo os dados, etc.. Se o problema da instalação foi resolvido vc marca como resposta e abre uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Olá bom dia, Desculpe a demora, mas seguinte qual msi devo baixar para minha aplicação, Abre mas não aparece nada norelatório.

Comment: Vc fala a versão? Se sim, pode instalar a última que está mais atualizada.

Comment: A última em questão seria essa "http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_14.zip"? Outra coisa, preciso configurar o conector ODBC?

Comment: Essa mesmo. Cara eu nos meus projetos eu n precisava configurar nada. Só instalar no servidor para ter as bibliotecas lá.

Comment: Vou testar aqui, Outra coisa, Há como instalar Silenciosamente no InnoSetup?

Comment: Não sei te dizer. Pra esse caso acho melhor vc abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: Está dano erro ao gerra o relatório, Tipo o sistema para de funcionar. O aplicativo funciona belezinha, mas guando peço para gerar o relatório trava o sistema e para rodar. Ele não dá msg de exceção do sistema, gera msg de erro do windows. O que pode ser? E abrir um post com pergunta anterior veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68332/instalar-crystal-report-silenciosamente-com-inno-setup